# splitting json object into an array, and assign other objects to each of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, split

[Original Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/27/) using the first JSON file

[Failed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/26/) using the second JSON file.

I have trouble using `split` and `$.each` function to return each small choice from an array.

I'm using a chained select box via AJAX from [this site](http://koviko.net/tutorial/building-an-accessible-client-side-chained-selection-drop-down). It requires a markup like this to build  chained select boxes:

```
<select>
    <option value="mustang2000">Ford » Mustang » 2000</option>
    <option value="mustang2005">Ford » Mustang » 2005</option>
    <option value="focus">Ford » Focus » 2010</option>
    <option value="alero">Oldsmobile » Alero » 1993</option>
</select>
```

Normally, the JSON file for the options would look like this:

First JSON file

```
[
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "mainstream",
    "choice": "football"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "mainstream",
    "choice": "basketball"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "niche",
    "choice": "MMA"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "niche",
    "choice": "wrestling"
  }
]
```

I want to stuff all the choices of the same category into one big choice using "|" as separators, like this:

Second JSON file

```
[
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "mainstream",
    "choice": "football|basketball"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "niche",
    "choice": "wrestling|racing"
  }
]
```

and in the script use `split` and `$.each` function to return each small choice

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%20%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FqMlPxn%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=", 
        success: function(data){
               var $select = $('select');var $option="";

        $.each(data.query.results.json.json, function (index, i) {

          smallchoice = i.choice.split(',');
        $.each(smallchoice,function(i,smallchoice){
         $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", smallchoice).text(i.bigcat + "@" +( i.cat || "") +"@" +  smallchoice);
       });

           $select.append($option); 
          });


        $select.dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"@"});
    } 
   });
```

But I have no idea how to assign `bigcat` and `cat` to each small choice. Can anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: In fact if you just specify that the `dataType` is `json` it will parse it for you so your `data` **is** an object.

Comment: Also, one thing I noticed, is that you need to be careful with the names of your variable and closures... especially `function(i,smallchoice)`when you had already declared the same variables few lines above. Change that for something else, like `function(j, choice)` and already I see something that's not "undefined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to manually parse your Json object. This is not needed with Jquery. Jquery has a built-in parseJson() method that can turn a well-formed json object into a javascript Object. Alternatively, as Liam recommends, you can also specify in your $.ajax() options that the dataType is json, which will automatically parse the resulting data response to an object.

You can then also use an array["wrestling","racing"] instead of a |-delimited list for your choice. These 2 methods combined can help you a lot and simplify your code.

so to summarize: add `dataType:"json",` to your ajax options and use an array to store choice instead of a delimited list.

(update from comment as suggested by meta).